# Access assets in outside from RoR project folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have an audio file in ~/auido/test.ogg and I want to create a link associated to it in my RoR, which in ~/project/my_app.

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "link" ? Symlink? Serve it from public? Read it from ruby?

Comment: To explain in detail, I want to create url like "http://test.com/auido/01" which can be used by html5 auido tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a slight modification to @Skydreamer's answer.

If you have an audio folder you want to serve (eg. ~/audio)

just symlink this to public.

```
ln -s ~/audio ~/project/my_app/public/
```

then you can access any file in ~/audio via the url "/audio"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using linux, you can use `ln` command like this : `ln -s ~/audio/test.ogg ~/project/my_app/assets/sounds/test.ogg`

Comment: This could solve problem indeed. But I don't want create symlink each times when I use this url. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found I could create a controller which read .ogg file like

`@test_ogg=File.open(~/audio/test.ogg,"rb").read`

and put it in html.erb like

`<%=raw(@test_ogg)%>`

And then I could access it from a url link "http://test.com/audio/01".

Thanks!